# c and c++ operators help

Tags: c++, c

can someone explain to me why the following results in b = 13?

```
int a, b, c;
a = 1|2|4;
b = 8;
c = 2;
b |= a;
b&= ~c;
```

Comment: Write down the value of `a`, `b` and `c` on a piece of paper after every step. Put it up here and tell us which part you don't understand.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is using binary manipultaors.  (Assuming ints are 1 byte, and use Two's complement for storage, etc.)

`a = 1|2|4` means `a = 00000001 or 00000010 or 00000100`, which is 00000111, or 7.
`b = 8` means `b = 00001000`.
`c = 2` means `c = 00000010`.
`b |= a` means `b = b | a` which means `b = 00001000 or 00000111`, which is 00001111, or 15.
`~c` means `not c`, which is 11111101.
`b &= ~c` means `b = b & ~c`, which means `b = 00001111 and 11111101`, which is 00001101, or 13.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node13.html

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 1|2|4
  = 0b001
  | 0b010
  | 0b100
  = 0b111
  = 7

b = 8 = 0b1000

c = 2 = 0b10

b|a = 0b1000
    | 0b0111
    = 0b1111 = 15

~c = 0b111...1101

(b|a) & ~c = 0b00..001111
           & 0b11..111101
           = 0b00..001101
           = 13
```

Answer (score 0):

lets go into binary mode:
a = 0111 (7 in decimal)
b = 1000 (8)
c = 0010 (2)

then we OR b with a to get b = 1111 (15)
c = 0010 and ~c = 1101
finally b is anded with negated c which gives us c = 1101 (13)

Answer (score 0):

hint: Convert decimal to binary and give it a shot.. maybe... just maybe you'll figure it all out by yourself

Answer (score 0):

`a = 1 | 2 | 4;`

Assigns the value 7 to `a`.  This is because you are performing a bitwise `OR` operation on the constants 1, 2 and 4.  Since the binary representation of each of these is 1, 10 and 100 respectively, you get 111 which is 7.

`b |= a;`

This `OR`s `b` and `a` and assigns the result to `b`.  Since `b`'s binary representation is now 111 and `a`'s binary representation is 1000 (8), you end up with 1111 or 15.

`b &= ~c;`

The `~c` in this expression means the bitwise negation of `c`.  This essentially flips all 0's to 1's and vice versa in the binary representation of `c`.  This means `c` switches from 10 to 111...11101.

After negating `c`, there is a bitwise `AND` operation between `b` and `c`.  This means only bits that are 1 in both `b` and `c` remain 1, all others equal 0.  Since `b` is now 1111 and `c` is all 1's except in the second lowest order bit, all of `b`'s bits remain 1 except the 2 bit.

The result of flipping `b`'s 2 bit is the same as if you simply subtracted 2 from its value.  Since its current value is 15, and 15-2 = 13, the assignment results in `b == 13`.